# how to set gitlab admin area setting by configuration file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

I am running gitlab `10.4.2-ce`, i have setting on artifacts size on admin area, any chance that I can set these values by some configuration files like `gitlab.rb` or others, thx you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not yet possible: [omnibus-gitlab issue 2729](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2729) follows that request.

> ## Add maximum artifact size option to `gitlab.rb`
>
> This is a feature request.
>
> It would be nice to be able to configure the maximum artifact size in `gitlab.rb` instead of needing to manually set it in the Admin Area for each fresh deployment.
>
> I would imagine adding another option to the Job Artifacts section under `gitlab_rails`, i.e. something like:
>
> ```
> gitlab_rails['artifacts_maximum_upload_size_MB'] = 256
> ```

Note that:

> When I made this issue, my intention was to make the maximum artifact upload size a larger number on a clean deployment, without having to set it by hand (because I wanted all of the configuration to be part of my infrastructure-as-code).
>
> I later found out that **this can be set via the API** and set it that way instead, so there isn't really an issue here.

Check out the "[Application settings API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/settings.html)". It does include:

`max_artifacts_size`    `integer`   Maximum artifacts size in MB

Comment: Thank you for linking to he API, that will come in very handy for me.